# Binary Search Tree Property

Tags: terminology, data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

In the book 'Introduction to Algorithms 3/e', I have found the following definition of Binary Search Tree property:

> Let $x$ be a node in a binary search tree. If $y$ is a node in the left subtree
>   of $x$, then $y.key \leq x.key$. If $y$ is a node in the right subtree of $x$, then $y.key \geq x.key$.

My confusion is that while implementing binary search trees we either consider that the keys of left-subtree of a node $x$ would be $\leq x.key$ **or** the keys of right-subtree of a node $x$ would be $\geq x.key$ but **not both**. That is we follow one of the two convention. But in the property they have included $=$ in both the cases. Where am I wrong?

I would appreciate any idea on this issue.

Answer (score 7):

You're not wrong, but neither are they. The normal formulation is to have the left subtree values be strictly less than ($<$) the current value and the right greater than or equal to ($\geq$) the current value, or vice versa ($\leq$ and $>$), however using $\leq$ and $\geq$ still results in a working BST in the sense that the tree provides an ordering. (Try constructing a few, you'll see that the difference is that if you have repeated values, they can get spread over the right-most part of the left subtree and the left-most part of the right subtree instead of being in one or the other).

To see that it still works, consider the cases when searching the tree:

1. $y = x$, you've already found it, so you can stop here;
2. $y < x$, it must be in the left subtree (if $y <x$ then $y \leq x$);
3. $y > x$, it must be in the right subtree.

So you can see that the operation is identical, the choice at each node remains unambiguous.

**EDIT** Just to highlight Svick's excellent point in the comments, if you're searching for all nodes with the same value, the "$\leq,\geq$" case introduces complications - it may require more than one pass to find all such nodes (a full traversal will get them all of course, if it's an [inorder traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_traversal) you even get them in a row).

Comment: But the choice can be ambiguous if you want to find all nodes with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

The equality is allowed when multiple nodes may have the same key.

Consider:

```
     c
  b     d
 a c   c e
```

In order to find all `c` elements, you have to descend both subtrees of the topmost `c`, but only the right subtree of `b`, and the left subtree of `d`.

Comment: So why they have such a property when we need to traverse both subtrees. Our target in tree searching would be to descend left or descend right. Is it to generalize tree ordering?

Comment: That depends on how the tree is balanced. If you rebalance the tree from my example so the rightmost `c` is on top, then you only need to go down the left path -- but then you have modified the constraint to disallow equality on the right subtree.

Comment: I got these ideas but my focus is why they at all allow equality on both sides. Balancing is a concept which is not present in basic binary search trees.

Comment: Precisely because they do not want to think about balancing. Different insertion orders then lead to different tree layouts, so equal nodes can lie on either side.